# Entity Framework dynamic filter query using ToTraceString vs sproc

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I have a grid view with complex filtering options, the query is built with 
an IQueryable on my dbcontext. This is working fine, the table can contain a lot of data, but the result is filtered with sane paging options.
I now have a requirement to implement an export feature that must work with all the filtering options available for the grid.

Let's say the table might contain a million rows.

I think I will run in performance issues by executing this with EF.
I also could create a stored procedure, but that would be quite complex and the logic will kind of be duplicated from the c# code.

Would it be a good idea to instead use the existing logic that build the IQueryable and generate the query string using

```
((System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery)myIqueryable).ToTraceString()
```

Then I can run the generated query with ExecuteStoreQuery (or any other way to run sql directly)?

I tested this and it seem to work fine, but I am not sure how the performance vs a stored procedure would be or if I will run into issues I did not think of.

Comment: I don't see why running the SQL generated by EF would be more efficient than letting EF run it. If your db sets are configured correctly (annotated with correct data types, etc) then EF is probably going to perform pretty close to the stored procedure as long as you create the SqlParameters correctly (don't use AddWithValue).

Comment: Well in the context of a data export, won't I gain performance by using the generated query with an SqlCommand and SQLDataReader? I don't really need the entities mapping in this case.

Comment: You may gain performance in your application, I thought you were concerned with the work done on the database server.